# custom swipe method for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipeview

How can I show all content from my tableview or my core data in another view controller with SWIPE METHOD for iOS?

Well this time I need to know how I can show all content or all object class from my core data entity. To better understand its like in the picture, that I looking for:
[image]

So, in my project its fine & run perfectly my add object method & show in the tableview. I have  a method for delete an item too from my tableview & works fine. From another question, I learn & run fine all methods for the example core data. But I need in another view controller to show all content or all objects from my class entity in SWIPE method, one for one. I did find some examples and tutorials with scrollview & paging control, or swipe method recognition but those are so simple and are not using a core data model.

its posible crate a swipe method like this example?:

[image]

but with dynamic views? with voids & functions from buttons, labels?

I did learn from the following tutorials:

1. http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/
2. https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwipeView
3. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ScrollViewPagingMode/ScrollViewPagingMode.html

But those tutorials & examples work fine with statics views or images. How can I use those methods to show all objects from my entity core data model, Im using xcode 4.6 & iOS 6, so I need your help!!! THANKS AGAIN!!!! XD

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want a horizontal UITableView (where virtualized cell is the description page of a developer). Are you targeting only iOS6? Then UICollectionView is good for the task:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html

WWDC 2012 stuffs about it:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=219

Its parent is UIScrollView so pagination is available also.